# Error while importing project to jBpm Business Central from gitlab

Tags: java, jboss, drools, jbpm, kie

I use Business Central from jBPM 7.29.0 to create drl files. I want to import my project from gitlab to bc. 
BC has next REST endpoint(https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.31.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_introduction_3):

```
POST {}:{}/business-central/rest/spaces/{space}/git/clone
{
  "name": "BusinessRules",
  "description": "Some desc",
  "userName": "my-user",
  "password": "1243",
  "gitURL": "git@gitlab.com:project/apps/business-rules.git"
}
```

I use correct username, password, url, but bc throws errors such as

```
13:00:05,800 ERROR [org.guvnor.rest.backend.cmd.AbstractJobCommand] (Thread-197) CloneProjectJobRequest [1585054803428-13] failed because of thrown GenericPortableException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.commands.Clone$CloneException: Error cloning origin <git@gitlab.com:project/apps/business-rules.git>.: org.guvnor.common.services.shared.exceptions.GenericPortableException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.commands.Clone$CloneException: Error cloning origin <git@gitlab.com:project/apps/business-rules.git>.

...

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@gitlab.com:project/apps/business-rules.git: Auth fail
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.commands.Fetch.execute(Fetch.java:68)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.GitImpl.fetch(GitImpl.java:280)
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.commands.Clone.execute(Clone.java:115)
        ... 33 more
```

With using UI I have same problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If both UI and REST fail, likely those credentials are wrong or do not have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas When I make git clone manually, everything ok. The username and password are exactly correct. If about permissions then account on gitlab has role maintainer. This is very strange.

Comment: When I try import project from public GitHub and from another business central - everything ok. May be need I change some ssh setting or put some certificates?

Comment: Have you configured SSH keys correctly?

Comment: I don't know. I have generated a ssh key with ssh-keygen on my local machine. And I added this key (id_rsa.pub) to business central(ssh key store) and to gitlab for my account. May be need I to set specific name for key? I don't have another ideas at the moment.

Comment: You can refer to documentation https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.33.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_using_the_ssh_keystore for setting up SSH key. Also, did you try using https URL for importing?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using the https url of course. Thanks, I will try again with manipulations with ssh keys.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am using the HTTPS version of importing in Business Central and my company uses Azure DevOps - which seems to require using personal access tokens (to replace usernames and passwords).

I've noticed in some versions of eGit there are issues with using the SSH protocol; are you using eGit to go to Business Central?  This is a common issue with developing in Eclipse and pushing repositories for Business Central

Comment: No unfortunately